# FileSystemWatcher how to fire multiple changes only one

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I have a simple test application:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class Form1
    Public watchfolder As FileSystemWatcher

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher("C:\\TEST")
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.DirectoryName Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.Size)

        AddHandler watchfolder.Changed, AddressOf Zmiana
        AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf Zmiana
        AddHandler watchfolder.Deleted, AddressOf Zmiana
        AddHandler watchfolder.Renamed, AddressOf Zmiana

        watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Zmiana()
        If txtTest.InvokeRequired Then
            txtTest.Invoke(Sub() txtTest.Text += "K")
        Else
            txtTest.Text += "K"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

What the application do is watching for changes in my directory *C:\Test*

If the change like Creating, Deleting, Renaming, Changing is occures the application writes a letter 'K' to the TextBox. It works fine. But when I for example copy 5 files to this directory the event fires 5 times (5 letter appears to the TextBox).

What I want to do is when I copy 5 files to that directory I want to raise an event only one time (one letter 'K' in TextBox). How can I achieve this?

Comment: A Timer trivially gets that job done.  You need one anyway since you rarely can do anything with the file at the exact moment that the event fires

Comment: To @HansPassant's point of rarely being able to do anything at the moment of the event, you'll need to decide when to actually take action, whether you use FileSystemWatcher events or a timer, since file writes aren't necessarily instantaneous.  Also, bear in mind that the `Changed` event may fire multiple times for the *same* file.